# ElasticSearch: array size inside of terms query cannot exceed 1000 indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like so:

`"filter": {
        "query": {
          "terms": { "user": ["jonh", "doe", ..., "asdf"]}
        }
    }`

The number of users in the array is arbitrarily big for our use case. However, ElasticSearch seems to fail with `"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure;` when the size of the array surpasses `1027`.

Is this the expected behavior? If so, is there a way to increase the size of the accepted array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your request is using terms **query**, which is getting translated into boolean query, which by default doesn't accept more than 1024 terms. However, since you are using it as a filter later on, it will be actually faster to switch to using terms **filter**, which doesn't have this limitation. All you have to do is remove [query filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-filter/) from your request:

```
"filter": { "terms": { "user": ["jonh", "doe", ..., "asdf"]} }
```

Comment: @ramseykhalaf I don't think so.

Comment: I am getting an average response of 10 seconds for 1 million users exclusion, is there a way it can be faster?